# Unable to reference class in main

Tags: c#, class, program-entry-point

The first two parameters seem to work but when I add the string I get an error (Line 17 cannot convert string to double). What am I missing here? From everything I've read in my book it seems like this should work so I'm guessing it's a stupid error but I've been looking up and down the code for the last 3 hours and haven't found anything. Thank you for reading this far!

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication14
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        SimpleCalc Calc = new SimpleCalc("{0.0}", "{0.0}", "{0}");
        Console.WriteLine(Calc);

    }
  }
}
```

This is the class

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication14
{
class SimpleCalc
{

        public SimpleCalc(double num1, double num2, string oper)
        {

            Console.Write("Enter first integer: ");
            num1 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.Write("Enter operator (+,-,*, / or %)");
            oper = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.Write("Enter second integer: ");
            num2 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

            if (oper == "+")
                Console.Write("Answer is: {0}", num1 + num2);

            if (oper == "-")
                Console.Write("Answer is: {0}", num1 - num2);

            if (oper == "*")
                Console.Write("Answer is: {0}", num1 * num2);

            if (oper == "/")
                Console.Write("Answer is: {0}", num1 / num2);

            if (oper == "%")
                Console.Write("Answer is: {0}", num1 % num2);

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @NitinVarpe: No, it's internal by default for top-level types.

Comment: It's also in the same namespace..

Comment: -1 for not telling us the error message and on which line of code it occurred. You can see the error message. Why should we be denied that information?

Comment: I think you should read about what parameters are about. Usually assigning a value to an input paramter such as `num1` is a bad idea.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead: Not that namespaces are relevant to access control...

Comment: What do you expect to happen when you pass the instance of SimpleCalc to Console.WriteLine?

Comment: @JonSkeet My point is that you can assume with fairly good accuracy that the types reside inside the same assembly.. given the question that was asked.

Comment: Sorry @DavidHeffernan, I copied it but forgot to paste it. I spent a long weekend in the field, my brain isn't working at full capacity at the moment.

Comment: It is still not there. You should edit the question to include the missing info.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Rog. Added it.

Comment: Thanks. I converted my -1 into a +1

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Thank you sir, appreciate it! Apologies for the inconvenience

Comment: @Dirk Thanks for the info, I will do that. I have a lot to go over and learn, I'll get the hang of it soon enough though. Thank you all for the help!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that your constructor takes two doubles and a string:

```
public SimpleCalc(double num1, double num2, string oper)
```

But you're calling it with three strings:

```
SimpleCalc Calc = new SimpleCalc("{0.0}", "{0.0}", "{0}");
```

Change that to:

```
SimpleCalc calc = new SimpleCalc(0.0, 0.0, "{0}");
```

and it should be fine, in terms of compiling. (It's not good that you're interacting with the user in a constructor, and ignoring the values of the parameters that were passed in, but that's a different matter.)

Also note that I've changed the name of the local variable from `Calc` to `calc` to follow normal C# conventions.

Comment: Yeah, don't know how that slipped my mind. I knew it was a stupid mistake, haha. Thanks man!

Comment: @JonSkeet you changed it to `calc` from `Calc` :)

Comment: @NitinVarpe: In the description, I assume you mean? Fixed.

Comment: @JonSkeet sorry but didnt get u. I was just pointing to some mistake in typing

Answer (score 3):

Your `SimpleCalc` constructor expects `double`s and a single `string` at the end.. you're passing it strings only.

So, instead of this:

```
SimpleCalc Calc = new SimpleCalc("{0.0}", "{0.0}", "{0}");
```

You should be doing something like this:

```
SimpleCalc Calc = new SimpleCalc(0.0, 0.0, "0");
```

Answer (score 0):

Well firstly you are some converion errors string to double and overload with invalid args.

Secondly you are passing parameters to constructor but not using them?

Maybe you want

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SimpleCalc Calc = new SimpleCalc();
        Console.WriteLine(Calc);
    }
```

and consructor as

```
    public SimpleCalc()
    {
        double num1;
        double num2;
        string oper;

        Console.Write("Enter first integer: ");
        num1 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.Write("Enter operator (+,-,*, / or %)");
        oper = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.Write("Enter second integer: ");
        num2 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

        if (oper == "+")
            Console.Write("Answer is: {0}", num1 + num2);

        if (oper == "-")
            Console.Write("Answer is: {0}", num1 - num2);

        if (oper == "*")
            Console.Write("Answer is: {0}", num1 * num2);

        if (oper == "/")
            Console.Write("Answer is: {0}", num1 / num2);

        if (oper == "%")
            Console.Write("Answer is: {0}", num1 % num2);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

your code had multiple bugs. If you are sending `parameters` from `Main` function from where you get this parameters. And If you send parameters from `Main` function why are you reading it from console in `SimpleCalc` function.

First remove reading part from `SimpleCalc` function to `Main`.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    double num1;
    double num2;
    string oper;

    Console.Write("Enter first integer: ");
    num1 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

    Console.Write("Enter operator (+,-,*, / or %)");
    oper = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());

    Console.Write("Enter second integer: ");
    num2 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

    SimpleCalc Calc = new SimpleCalc(num1,num2,oper);
    Console.WriteLine(Calc);
}
```

and remove reading part from function and make it simple and clear

```
    public SimpleCalc(double num1, double num2, string oper)
    {

        if (oper == "+")
            Console.Write("Answer is: {0}", num1 + num2);

        if (oper == "-")
            Console.Write("Answer is: {0}", num1 - num2);

        if (oper == "*")
            Console.Write("Answer is: {0}", num1 * num2);

        if (oper == "/")
            Console.Write("Answer is: {0}", num1 / num2);

        if (oper == "%")
            Console.Write("Answer is: {0}", num1 % num2);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass correct type of argument what you have initiated in the method. Refer below code.

SimpleCalc Calc = new SimpleCalc(0.0, 0.0, "0");

or

You can pass like below.

SimpleCalc Calc = new SimpleCalc("{0.0}", "{0.0}", "{0}");

But you need create the method as required like below

```
class SimpleCalc
{
    public SimpleCalc(string num1, string num2, string oper)
    {
        //............
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As everyone already pointed you to the problem with the parameters type passed to the constructor of your class I wish to point a logical problem in your code

The parameters passed to the SimpleCalc constructor becomes local variable inside the constructor and are not used at all because you ask you user to type the value for them. So why passing them in the first instance? I also find not a good example the fact that all the works of your class is executed in the constructor (taking also the input without any validation).

Perhaps you should use a different approach

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // To keep short, I have not added any validation, but the user input
    // should always validated See double.TryParse 

    Console.Write("Enter first integer: ");
    double num1 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

    Console.Write("Enter operator (+,-,*, / or %)");
    string oper = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());

    Console.Write("Enter second integer: ");
    double num2 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
    SimpleCalc calc = new SimpleCalc(num1, num2, oper);
    double result = calc.Execute();
    Console.WriteLine("Answer is: {0}", result);
}

class SimpleCalc
{
    double _num1;
    double _num2;
    string _oper;
    public SimpleCalc(double num1, double num2, string oper)
    {
        _num1 = num1;
        _oper = oper;
        _num2 = num2;
    }
    public double Execute()
    {        
        if (oper == "+")
            return num1 + num2;

        else if (oper == "-")
            return num1 - num2;

        else if (oper == "*")
            return num1 * num2;

        else if (oper == "/")
            return num1 / num2;

        else if (oper == "%")
            return num1 % num2;

        else 
             throw new ArgumentException("Invalid operator: " + oper);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You Should use it as below
    SimpleCalc Calc = new SimpleCalc(0.0, 0.0, "{0}");

As your Class expects first two params as double and 3rd one as a string

Comment: I am not the question poster :)